# How to "Get Latest Version" from Azure DevOps TFVC via api

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a .NET application hosted in Azure Devops TFVC (https://****.visualstudio.com/).

I want to programmatically get the latest version with is equivalent to click "**Get latest version** (recursive)" in Visual Studio.

I have already searched but cannot find an example to do this simple task.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exact do "Get Latest" in C# it's available onlt in the TFS old API Library. if you install the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ExtendedClient` NuGet it should be there.

An example how to use it:

```
connection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("azure devops url"));
connection.Authenticate();
var = versionControl = connection .GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var worksapce = versionControl.GetWorkspace("local-path-of-the-workspace");
// Do the "Get Latest":
workspace.Get();
```

Another option is to use `tf.exe` [utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands) and execute it from c# code like each `.exe` file.

Answer (score 0):

There are REST Api availble for AzureDevOps to pull latest source.

For authenticating your client you can use [Device Profile](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-deviceprofile/?v=17.23h) and can create the url in below pattern to access the server to fetch the code.

```
VERB https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis[/{area}]/{resource}?api-version={version}
```

Below is code in C# taken from the same sample using `HttpClient` class to connect.

```
public static async void GetProjects()
{
    try
    {
        var personalaccesstoken = "PAT_FROM_WEBSITE";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
                        "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects"))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

There is a complete walkthrough available. [Azure DevOps Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)

Comment: tried your code with Personal Access Tokens. there is no exception but no file is downloaded. In the bottom of the responsebody there is this "Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator"

Comment: Please configure the security settings for ie as mentioned in the article here.
[link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/815141/ie-enhanced-security-configuration-changes-browsing-experience)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do this same task when I found your post here.  I found the documentation for how to do this on Microsoft but they did not provide an example.  Your REST call might look something like this, though:

```
https://****.visualstudio.com/<your info>/_apis/tfvc/items?scopePath=$/folder_to_get&versionType=Latest&versionOptions=None&recursionLevel=full
```

This should return you all objects under your folder in a flat array with the version number, etc, for each item.

Full documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#versioncontrolrecursiontype)